# Dart Switch with range

Tags: dart

Is there a way in dart to switch between ranges. I couldn't find anything except [clamp](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/num/clamp.html)

For example:

```
switch(response.statusCode) {
  case 200..300: return "OK";
  case 400..500: return "Error";
  default: break;
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Not possible with switch. Use `if/else if` with `>=` and `<=` to achieve the same result.

```
if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 300) {
    return "OK";
}
else if (response.statusCode >= 400 && response.statusCode <= 500) {
    return "Error";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That is actually what I did. I was just wondering if there is a smarter solution.

Answer (score 31):

The accepted answer is not fully true anymore!
With dart 3.0 it is now possible to write:

```
 switch(response.statusCode) {
  case >= 200 && < 300: return "OK";
  case >= 400 && < 500: return "Error";
  default: break;
 }

// or even

return switch(response.statusCode) {
  >= 200 && < 300 => "OK";
  >= 400 && < 500 => "Error";
  _ => "Unexpected Case";
 }
```